# Host application as default site in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I have hosted asp.net mvc application as an application called "samples" inside default website in wwwroot folder in IIS7.0. The url www.website.com/samples will show the application but i want the url www.website.com to show the application.

I have set default document as below.

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
<files>
<clear />
<add value="Index.aspx" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Also i have placed the Index.aspx in root folder. I am getting the below error

The file '/Views/Shared/Site.Master' does not exist.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

I have searched and found setting default document will work but getting above error.

Can anyone suggest the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be deployed to the root folder for which the web site is configured for:

[image]

So in this example you deploy your application in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` directly. No subfolders.

Comment: Thanks. I want to know how to configure the sub-directory application for default website

Comment: You put `c:\inetput\wwwroot\subdirectory` as physical path for your web site.

Comment: That will work. I want to use the default documents concept. I don't want to change physical path of default website.

Comment: defaultDocuments is for static files only. It won't work for an ASP.NET MVC application.